# App not compatible with buildpack: error during deploying django app to heroku

Tags: django, heroku

I am trying to deploy django app to heroku.
During attempt of deployment, I'm getting an error: App not compatible with buildpack
I'm doing this the first time and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.
May be my master branch is on the venw directory and the directory of the app is on the main branch.
I have tried use call: git push heroku main on the main branch but it doesn't work.
My main branch contains files requirements.txt, procfile and runtime.txt.
It is necessary to push the app to heroku from the master branch or the main branch is also possible?
Any idea how to solve my problem?

My git bash logs below:

ggb@DESKTOP-PNHHOHJ MINGW64 /c/projekty/tabele/tabenv (master)
$ ls
Include/  Lib/  pyvenv.cfg  requiremenrs.txt  runtime.txt  Scripts/  tabele/
(tabenv)
gg@DESKTOP-PNHHOHJ MINGW64 /c/projekty/tabele/tabenv (master)
$ git push heroku master
Enumerating objects: 9191, done.
Counting objects: 100% (9191/9191), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (5820/5820), done.
Writing objects: 100% (9191/9191), 17.71 MiB | 4.76 MiB/s, done.
Total 9191 (delta 2299), reused 9184 (delta 2296), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
remote:        More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: 369abf675a4a69d7c758eabf0cdfa0c0b8711a39
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version 369abf675a4a69d7c758eabf0cdfa0c0b8711a39
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku :main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to thawing-falls-31558.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/thawing-falls-31558.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/thawing-falls-31558.git'
(tabenv)
gg@DESKTOP-PNHHOHJ MINGW64 /c/projekty/tabele/tabenv (master)
$

```
gg@DESKTOP-PNHHOHJ MINGW64 /c/projekty/tabele/tabenv/tabele (main)
$ ls
db.sqlite3  manage.py*  requiremenrs.txt  staticfiles/
formula/    Procfile    runtime.txt       tabele/
(tabenv)
gg@DESKTOP-PNHHOHJ MINGW64 /c/projekty/tabele/tabenv/tabele (main)
$ git push heroku main
Enumerating objects: 155, done.
Counting objects: 100% (155/155), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (144/144), done.
Writing objects: 100% (155/155), 177.22 KiB | 2.27 MiB/s, done.
Total 155 (delta 62), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
remote:        More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: eaefbfee8a53854c985b523ac2371f3881297e6d
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version eaefbfee8a53854c985b523ac2371f3881297e6d
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to pure-earth-78865.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/pure-earth-78865.git
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/pure-earth-78865.git'
(tabenv)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
remote:        More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
```

The `detect` script for the Python buildpack can be found here: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/blob/main/bin/detect

```
if [ ! -f "$BUILD_DIR/requirements.txt" ] && [ ! -f "$BUILD_DIR/setup.py" ] && [ ! -f "$BUILD_DIR/Pipfile" ]; then
  exit 1
fi
```

It checks for a presence of `requirements.txt`, `setup.py` or `Pipfile` in the root directory of your git repo. It is not present in your case thus it is failing.

Comment: Thanks for help. This is my first django project. Could you tell me in what exactly moment can I use this code. Should I create special file in folder including manage.py file or somewhere else.

Comment: I have realized that you mean, than i have to edit one of scripts of the builpacks. Could you tell me how can I get acces to it?

Comment: You misunderstood. You need `requirements.txt`, `setup.py` or `Pipfile` in the root directory of your git repo. It is not present in your case thus it is failing.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, heroku deployment was failing because of how my app was structured: my flask app was in a subdirectory within a git repo.

As pointed out by Tin Nguyen, `requirements.txt, setup.py, Pipfile` and also `Procfile` need to be at the root. So instead of `git push heroku master` (or main) it should be:

```
git subtree push --prefix path/to/app-subdir heroku master
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is often from your requirements.text file or Profile. Double check these files and ensure git is not ignoring them